# Class Object to Protocol

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have a model class fake Repository which implements a Delegate Method:

.h

```
@interface FakeAccountRepository : NSObject <AccountRepositoryDelegate>
@end
```

.m

```
    @implementation FakeAccountRepository
-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
       // statements
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the protocol and delegate:

```
@protocol AccountRepositoryDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (NSArray *)accountRegistered;

@end
```

In the View Controller, what is the meaning of this :

```
id <AccountRepositoryDelegate> fakeRepository = [[FakeAccountRepository alloc] init];
```

I mean "`[[FakeAccountRepository alloc] init]`" is returning an object of the FakeRepository class. Then what is this assigning happening ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
[[FakeAccountRepository alloc] init];
```

obviously creates an instance of the `FakeAccountRepository` class. And, as you know, this class happens to conform to the `AccountRepositoryDelegate` protocol.

The declaration:

```
id <AccountRepositoryDelegate> fakeRepository
```

is creating a variable named `fakeRepository` and its type is `id <AccountRepositoryDelegate>`. `id` means an object reference to any object type. The `<AccountRepositoryDelegate>` of course references the `AccountRepositoryDelegate` protocol. Together they mean that the variable can be of any object type as long as that object conforms to the `AccountRepositoryDelegate` protocol.

Basically, `id<SomeProtocol>` means that you can assign any object that conforms to the given protocol.

You can see plenty of examples of this in the iOS APIs. For example, the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of `UITableView` are defined as `id<UITableViewDataSource>` and `id<UITableViewDelegate>` respectively.